# PHP5 include() Problem

Tags: php, include, smarty

So, I've got task from my boss to install opendocman on our newly installed PHP5 running on openbsd.
When I try to install opendocman on my ubuntu laptop (running 9.04) it was run smoothly. But, when I try to install in on server, I've got these error:

```
Warning: include(templates_c/%%0E^0E4^0E407559%%footer.tpl.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/www/apache22/data/myphp/opendocman/includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1258

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'templates_c/%%0E^0E4^0E407559%%footer.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /usr/local/www/apache22/data/myphp/opendocman/includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1258
```

My though, this is generated because of some misconfigured on php.ini, but I can't find the specific setting. Care for some help or guidance? I google a bit but no result (maybe wrong keyword:().

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using a template engine called [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). templates_c is where Smarty compiles *.tpl files to PHP. Check your Webserver has permissions to write to this directory. The normal setup for a Webserver is that it can't write to anything but it needs to write to the templates_c directory.

I'd suggest you peruse the [Smarty Manual](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/), especially [Basic Installation](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/installing.smarty.basic.php).

I just had a look. Opendocman does in fact use Smarty as a templating engine so I'm fairly sure it's a permissions problem you have.

Alternatively you may want to delete the contents of the templates_c directory to force a refresh (ie a recompile of the original templates).

Comment: haha, thank you. I never use smarty, therefore, I though it was miss-configuration on php's side. just add 'x' on it's permission remove the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like opendocman configuration issues.